# Subscribe topic from library?

Tags: ros, library, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just a small question: is it possible to subscribe to a `topic` from within a library, say, like a `costmap_2d` layer plugin, and if it is, how is it done?

I've tried to just call NodeHandle::subscribe from the library. The call itself works, however the callback method is never executed.

Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/80576/subscribe-topic-from-library?/) by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1145 on 2013-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just do it exactly like in any other code: Make a NodeHandle an subscribe using that.

The only things to look out for: Someone must have called ros::init (usually the main program using the library) and at least one NodeHandle must still be alive.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hendrik Wiese](https://answers.ros.org/users/295/hendrik-wiese/) on 2013-09-18**:
So with regard to the costmap_2d layers I've tried exactly that. Apparently ros::init isn't called anywhere nor is ros::spin and so messages don't arrive in my layer plugin lib. Well, I'm using a different approach now: I create another point cloud from my data and hand it to another ObstacleLayer.